# C++: Get value from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that I pass a pointer to a vector of unsigned char.

Can somebody please tell me how to get one of the values inside the function?

```
double CApp::GetCost(unsigned char *uBytes)
{
   unsigned char iHP;
   iHP=uBytes[49]; //this does not work
}
```

Edit: 
Sorry, I first thought that I should simplify my code, but I think too much can go wrong. Now here is the real declaration:

```
// ---------------------------------------
struct ByteFeature
{
    unsigned char Features[52];
};

class clsByteFeatures : public CBaseStructure
{
private:
   vector<ByteFeature> m_content;

protected:
   virtual void ProcessTxtLine(string line);

public:
   vector<ByteFeature> &Content();
   void Add(ByteFeature &bf);
};

vector<ByteFeature> &clsByteFeatures::Content()
{
   return m_content;
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
dblTargetCost  = GetCost(m_ByteFeatures.Content()[iUnitID].Features);
```

Another question:
Would it be bad to simply pass the vector like this?

```
double CApp::GetCost(vector<unsigned char> &uBytes)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: It is correct syntax. Why "ofcourse"?

Comment: The second approach is better than the first one.

Comment: Also, if you're not planning on modifying that vector, pass it `const` by-ref, sir.

Comment: I remember now why I have chosen the pointer instead of the vector. struct MyBytes
{
 unsigned char MyByteValues[52];
}; I can not pass this as a vector, I think, so I need to use a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Would it be bad to simply pass the vector like this?
double CApp::GetCost(vector<unsigned char> &uBytes)
```

Not it's the better way to pass it by reference. however you may want to add const qualifier if you don't want `uBytes` to be modified.

```
double CApp::GetCost(const vector<unsigned char> &uBytes)
{
   try
   {
     unsigned char iHP = uBytes.at(49);
     //... 
   }
   catch(std::exception& e)
   {
     // process e
   }
   //...
}
```

EDIT:

After you new post, I feel you only need to return a reference to the element of m_content then pass the reference to `GetCost` function

```
ByteFeature& clsByteFeatures::operator[](int i) { return m_content.at(i); }


double GetCost(const ByteFeature& bf)
{
    std::cout << bf.Features[49]; << std::endl;
    return 0.0;
}
```

then you call:

```
GetCost(m_ByteFeatures[iUnitID]);
```

Comment: I guess m_ByteFeatures is instance of clsByteFeatures ?